# Problem in going to definition in visual studio codes

Tags: embedded

I wanted to defined the Chip select pin of my spi,in the SPI master example.
I am using the recommended visual studio codes.
but when i tried to right click and going to definition it said that its not defined.
I have shown the directory and visual studio code window photos bellow.
Where did i go wrong?
Why i cant see the definition of the SPI variable? i need it to define the API
Thanks.

C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\esp-idf-4\esp\esp-idf
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the code compile?

Comment: in ESP-IDF its compiling in separate console ,its not like in eclipse.

Comment: This should be in some header spi_common.h and you need to link the library for that one too. If you think you have included and linked those correctly, then its some IDE path hiccup. You'll probably have more luck getting help this IDE at stackoverflow.com than here.

Comment: if the code compiles then that suggests the code is correct and the issue is with your project configuration under Visual Studio Code - the c/c++ syntax checker doesn't know how to find the various folders etc. Personally I use the PlatformIO plugin and this manages most things for me.